How to pull data by row from multiple sheets based on a drop down list?
I am working on a workbook that has multiple sheets. There are a few columns that are Y/Ns. I was trying to pull entire rows from other sheets based off of a Y/N drop down list, so if I needed to know what reports have certain terms hardcoded, I could get an entire aggregate instead of going to each tab and filtering. Is there a way to do this?


Report A Data Table



Report Name
Report Link
Year Hardcoded: Y/N
Type Hardcoded: Y/N?
Folder




Report A
www.reporta.com
Y
N
Report A's


Report A1
www.reporta1.com
N
Y
Report A's


Report A2
www.reporta2.com
Y
N
Report A's


Report A3
www.reporta3.com
N
Y
Report A's


Report A4
www.reporta4.com
Y
N
Report A's


Report A5
www.reporta5.com
N
Y
Report A's


Report A6
www.reporta6.com
Y
N
Report A's




Report B Data Table



Report Name
Report Link
Year Hardcoded: Y/N
Type Hardcoded: Y/N?
Folder




Report B
www.reportb.com
Y
N
Report B's


Report B1
www.reportb1.com
N
Y
Report B's


Report B2
www.reportb2.com
Y
N
Report B's


Report B3
www.reportb3.com
N
Y
Report B's


Report B4
www.reportb4.com
Y
N
Report B's


Report B5
www.reportb5.com
N
Y
Report B's


Report B6
www.reportb6.com
Y
N
Report B's




I have tried different variations of the INDIRECT formula, but I am having trouble pulling complete rows of data, including from multiple sheets.

Here is one possible method, you could try, instead of using any volatile functions like INDIRECT()


• Formula used in cell A3
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK('*'!A2:E8),
     FILTER(_Data, (INDEX(_Data,,3)=H2)*(INDEX(_Data,,4)=H3),""))


Also, instead of using ranges i would convert my source data's in respective sheets into Structured References aka Tables and use the following way:
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(ReportA,ReportB),
     FILTER(_Data, (INDEX(_Data,,3)=H2)*(INDEX(_Data,,4)=H3),""))


NOTE: that I have named both the tables as ReportA and ReportB and used the VSTACK() function to append each of the data one upon the other, while the first one uses the 3D-Reference feature of VSTACK() where the * refers to the sheet names and once its entered in the desired cell the formulas will reflect Report A:Report B this in place of *.

So, basically this is what you will get to see in the Excel:
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK('Report A:Report B'!A2:E8),
     FILTER(_Data, (INDEX(_Data,,3)=H2)*(INDEX(_Data,,4)=H3),""))


Similarly, if you are reluctant to use Structured References aka Tables and want to use some dynamic ways by banking on each sheets Column A as the base column, then:
=LET(
     _ReportA, 'Report A'!A2:INDEX('Report A'!A:E,MATCH(2,1/('Report A'!A:A<>"")),),
     _ReportB, 'Report B'!A2:INDEX('Report B'!A:E,MATCH(2,1/('Report B'!A:A<>"")),),
     _Append, VSTACK(_ReportA,_ReportB),
     FILTER(_Append,(INDEX(_Append,,3)=H2)*(INDEX(_Append,,4)=H3),""))


But note the above will lack efficiency, hence its suggested to use the one with Tables Version.

Some reference on usage of 3D-Reference with Dynamic array formulas posted by me long time back, can refer here as well, oh not only VSTACK() or HSTACK() does it but also TOCOL() and TOROW() works as well, quite elegantly. Here are two examples, there are few more, do research, will find nice use cases.
• Reference One: Dated - 3/3/2024
Excel formula for searching string across columns and filtering results

• Reference One: Dated - 3/16/2024
Excel formula to find duplicates from multiple sheets and list down on a new sheet or master sheet


3-D Reference may work here
Create a 3-D reference to the same cell range on multiple worksheets - Microsoft Support
Thanks to rachel for making me aware of this

Assuming the reports have same structure
Adjust the range $A$2:$E$1000 to match your data

=LET(
    report_data, VSTACK('Report A:Report B'!$A$2:$E$1000),
    header, 'Report A'!$A$1:$E$1,
    year_hardcoded_selection, $H$1,
    type_hardcoded_selection, $H$2,
    col_nums_in_result, XMATCH({"Report Name", "Report Link", "Folder"}, header),
    filtered, FILTER(
        CHOOSECOLS(report_data, col_nums_in_result),
        (
            INDEX(report_data, , XMATCH("Year Hardcoded: Y/N", header)) =
                year_hardcoded_selection
        ) *
            (
                INDEX(report_data, , XMATCH("Type Hardcoded: Y/N?", header)) =
                    type_hardcoded_selection
            )
    ),
    VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(header, col_nums_in_result), filtered)
)


